# Singleton object for database class - but for multiple databases

Tags: singleton

Background: I am writing a C# class for a Windows Application that will act as a customized Sql Server class that includes custom error checking.  And this class will allow for the general SQL functions: executing queries, connecting to database, closing connections, etc.

My scenario is this: I have two separate databases that I need to connect to at the same time.  But I want to implement the Singleton pattern so that only one connection can be established for each database (so a total of two connections open at once, but one to each database).  I want to prevent a second connection to either database from being established.

I thought about the Flyweight pattern, but I don't think that would apply in this case and that if I can get the Singleton pattern to work somehow it would be the better solution...  I can always just not use Singleton and have two database objects, or I can create an "open" flag in the class to be checked when a new connection is requested to see if an existing connection is open, and handle based on that...

Ideas / How can I do this?

Comment: I am curious, why would you want to prevent multiple connections to be established to a database? In a regular SQL Server database scenario, it is better to open and close connections for single operations, rather than keeping them open for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Factory Pattern for this.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm